# Create dump of a schema in a proper view

Tags: sql, postgresql, dump

I have created a table with this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE a(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY
);
```

I dumped the schema. The content of the dump looks similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE a(
    id integer
);

ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

The question is how can I create the dump of a database in the same view I executed statements?

I mean how can I get a dump with the content like:

```
CREATE TABLE a(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, and that is by design.

If the table contains data, these are loaded between the two statements you quote to get the best performance.

Moreover, there are many ways to create this table, for example

```
CREATE TABLE a (
   id integer,
   CONSTRAINT a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

PostgreSQL does not record the statement that was used to create the table.

I wonder why you would want that at all. The statements from the dump create the table just as well as your single statement.